# Unable to start visual studios 2019 (16.4)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I updated my visual studios to 16.4 and now I am unable to even open the IDE.

This is the error I'm receiving. 
[image]

- I've tried to repair and got the same error
- I did a complete removal using `Geek Uninstaller` and reinstalled and i still get the same error.
- Safemode produces same error message

Googleing the error messages solutions [similar to this one](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/569009/unable-to-start-visual-studio-1610-p3.html)

Ironicly, I first tried to report this to the visual studios team which ultimately leads me to [this link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=8). The problem is, I **cant** open visual studios.

I did manage to open a support request, but I don't expect a response for a few days, and I need to get my development setup up and running, so that's why I'm posting here too.

E: Forgot the log

E2: I lied, I was not able to open a support request. Appearently I have to pay?

E3: Safemode -> same error

```
12/05/2019 15:26:11 Eastern Standard Time : Error : Failed to start host 'desktopClr.x86$IdentityHost': Microsoft.ServiceHub.Utility.ServiceHubError: code: 'Hub host 'IdentityHost', PID: 9636 exited.'-532462766. (ErrorKind: HostExited) HResult='-2146233088' 
12/05/2019 15:26:11 Eastern Standard Time : Error : Error starting service 'IdentityStorageService' requested by StorageServiceClient (pid:2456): Failed to start host 'desktopClr.x86$IdentityHost' (ErrorKind: Error HResult: 8013153B)
12/05/2019 15:26:11 Eastern Standard Time : Error : Microsoft.ServiceHub.Utility.ServiceHubError: Failed to start host 'desktopClr.x86$IdentityHost' (ErrorKind: Error HResult: 8013153B) HResult='-2146233088' 
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Controller.LocationService.<StartServiceAsync>d__54.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Controller.LocationService.<GetHostedServiceLocationAsync>d__71.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Controller.LocationService.<LocateAsync>d__39.MoveNext()
===InnerException===
System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled. HResult='-2146233029' 
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.ThreadingTools.<WithCancellationSlow>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Controller.HostInfo.<GetEndPointAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Controller.LocationService.<StartServiceAsync>d__54.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
12/05/2019 15:26:13 Eastern Standard Time : Error : Error starting service 'IdentityStorageService' requested by StorageServiceClient (pid:2456): Failed to start host 'desktopClr.x86$IdentityHost' (ErrorKind: Error HResult: 8013153B)
12/05/2019 15:26:13 Eastern Standard Time : Error : Failed to start host 'desktopClr.x86$IdentityHost': Microsoft.ServiceHub.Utility.ServiceHubError: code: 'Hub host 'IdentityHost', PID: 5076 exited.'-532462766. (ErrorKind: HostExited) HResult='-2146233088' 
12/05/2019 15:26:13 Eastern Standard Time : Error : Microsoft.ServiceHub.Utility.ServiceHubError: Failed to start host 'desktopClr.x86$IdentityHost' (ErrorKind: Error HResult: 8013153B) HResult='-2146233088' 
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Controller.LocationService.<StartServiceAsync>d__54.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Controller.LocationService.<GetHostedServiceLocationAsync>d__71.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Controller.LocationService.<LocateAsync>d__39.MoveNext()
===InnerException===
System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled. HResult='-2146233029' 
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.ThreadingTools.<WithCancellationSlow>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Controller.HostInfo.<GetEndPointAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Controller.LocationService.<StartServiceAsync>d__54.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
12/05/2019 15:26:13 Eastern Standard Time : Error : Error starting service 'VsixServiceDiscovery' requested by VsixServiceDiscovery-extensionManager (pid:10144): Failed to start host 'desktopClr.x86$VSDetouredHost' (ErrorKind: Error HResult: 8013153B)
12/05/2019 15:26:13 Eastern Standard Time : Error : Microsoft.ServiceHub.Utility.ServiceHubError: Failed to start host 'desktopClr.x86$VSDetouredHost' (ErrorKind: Error HResult: 8013153B) HResult='-2146233088' 
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Controller.LocationService.<StartServiceAsync>d__54.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Controller.LocationService.<GetHostedServiceLocationAsync>d__71.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Controller.LocationService.<LocateAsync>d__39.MoveNext()
===InnerException===
System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled. HResult='-2146233029' 
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.ThreadingTools.<WithCancellationSlow>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Controller.HostInfo.<GetEndPointAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Controller.LocationService.<StartServiceAsync>d__54.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
12/05/2019 15:26:13 Eastern Standard Time : Error : StreamJsonRpc.RemoteInvocationException: Failed to start host 'desktopClr.x86$VSDetouredHost' (ErrorKind: Error HResult: 8013153B) HResult='-2146233088' 
   at StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.<InvokeCoreAsync>d__96`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Framework.RemoteServiceBroker.<GetPipeAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Client.HubClient.<GetPipeAsync>d__33.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Client.HubClient.<RequestServiceAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Controller.DiscoveryServiceProxy.<GetDiscoveryServiceProxyAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
12/05/2019 15:26:13 Eastern Standard Time : Error : Error starting service 'extensionManager' requested by ExtensionManagerServiceProxy (pid:2456): Cannot find service module info file 'extensionManager.servicehub.service.json' in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\ServiceHub\Services' (ErrorKind: ServiceModuleInfoNotFound)
12/05/2019 15:26:13 Eastern Standard Time : Error : Microsoft.ServiceHub.Utility.ServiceHubError: Cannot find service module info file 'extensionManager.servicehub.service.json' in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\ServiceHub\Services' (ErrorKind: ServiceModuleInfoNotFound) HResult='-2146233088' 
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Controller.ServiceDiscovery.<GetServiceModuleInfoAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Controller.LocationService.<GetHostedServiceLocationAsync>d__71.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Controller.LocationService.<LocateAsync>d__39.MoveNext()
12/05/2019 15:26:14 Eastern Standard Time : Error : Error starting service 'IdentityStorageService' requested by StorageServiceClient (pid:2456): Failed to start host 'desktopClr.x86$IdentityHost' (ErrorKind: Error HResult: 8013153B)
12/05/2019 15:26:14 Eastern Standard Time : Error : Failed to start host 'desktopClr.x86$IdentityHost': Microsoft.ServiceHub.Utility.ServiceHubError: code: 'Hub host 'IdentityHost', PID: 12996 exited.'-532462766. (ErrorKind: HostExited) HResult='-2146233088' 
12/05/2019 15:26:14 Eastern Standard Time : Error : Microsoft.ServiceHub.Utility.ServiceHubError: Failed to start host 'desktopClr.x86$IdentityHost' (ErrorKind: Error HResult: 8013153B) HResult='-2146233088' 
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Controller.LocationService.<StartServiceAsync>d__54.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Controller.LocationService.<GetHostedServiceLocationAsync>d__71.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Controller.LocationService.<LocateAsync>d__39.MoveNext()
===InnerException===
System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled. HResult='-2146233029' 
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.ThreadingTools.<WithCancellationSlow>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Controller.HostInfo.<GetEndPointAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Controller.LocationService.<StartServiceAsync>d__54.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
12/05/2019 15:26:15 Eastern Standard Time : Error : Error starting service 'IdentityStorageService' requested by StorageServiceClient (pid:2456): Failed to start host 'desktopClr.x86$IdentityHost' (ErrorKind: Error HResult: 8013153B)
12/05/2019 15:26:15 Eastern Standard Time : Error : Microsoft.ServiceHub.Utility.ServiceHubError: Failed to start host 'desktopClr.x86$IdentityHost' (ErrorKind: Error HResult: 8013153B) HResult='-2146233088' 
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Controller.LocationService.<StartServiceAsync>d__54.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Controller.LocationService.<GetHostedServiceLocationAsync>d__71.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Controller.LocationService.<LocateAsync>d__39.MoveNext()
===InnerException===
System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled. HResult='-2146233029' 
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.ThreadingTools.<WithCancellationSlow>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Controller.HostInfo.<GetEndPointAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Controller.LocationService.<StartServiceAsync>d__54.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
```

Comment: You'll need to get your machine fixed.  The one item that's always on top of the list, and emphasized by the kind of mishap, is anti-malware.  Disable it and try again.

Comment: @HansPassant can you clarify? Im not quite following. How would i get malware from updating visual studios using the installer? I installed the preview 16.5 and that opens without issues.

Comment: same problem here. not able to fix it yet

Answer (score 1):

I believe Hans' comment is referring to your anti-malware potentially blocking or delaying something it shouldn't during VS startup, rather than you getting malware from updating VS.

I'm currently working through this issue with our IT dept, since we don't have the ability to configure or disable these features on our own. Before this, our blocker was preventing part of the update/repair process. After resolving that, it persisted with this new error.

If you do have the ability to disable your malware checker/blocker and try the process again, it could be a telling troubleshooting method.

I'll update if/when this is resolved for me.

Comment: This is on a personal machine with little to no protection. (Windows firewall, defender all disabled, no 3rd party security software). So unless something else is going on that i'm unaware of, nothing *should* block the installation process. Please do keep me updated, i'm curious as to what caused this for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem. I believe caused by using system restore to restore back to before VS 16.4.1 upgrade in order to fix a hardware problem attributed to a Windows Update. Hardware problem was fixed by editing the registry. With VS I tried repair twice without success. Finally uninstall and re-install using Visual Studio Installer has resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

These Steps work for me.

Step 1: User left click on "Start (button)"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRFJr.png)

Step 2:Type the "Visual Studio Installer" [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jp2pU.png)

Step Final:
Goto the more-> repair.

its works for me.
thanks.

Comment: @lizzy91 had already specified that repairing did not work for them.

Comment: Yes, but the question explicitly specifies that repairing is not working. So your answer can't be a solution to this question.

Comment: It did work for me using Visual Studio 2019 on Mac mini M1 chip via Parallels. Thanks!